# Layoutmanager to add (GUI) controls on top of JComponent

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am not terribly experienced with building GUIs or using swing- any advise on this question would be appreciated

I'm coding a simple map application in Java where the map is drawn as a separate class extending a `JComponent`. I want to add GUI elements (buttons, textfields) on top to interact with the map - zooming, searching for addresses etc. I tried to use `BorderLayout` which seemed to place elements "outside" the map and the most desirable would be to have these elements ON the map.

Any hardened GUI folks out there that can recommend a `LayoutManager` that allows me to do this seamlessly?

- Adding elements on top of a JComponent
- Allows resizing

Thank you in advance!

Comment: use setLayout(null) and manually place your components over your map component

Comment: I know you are new to this but have you considered writing your own layout manager? I tried it and it's really not as hard as it may seem (provided that you don't want to do very complicated things) also you could create a layout manager that is only designed for this purpose so you can hard code the relative locations of different components(you can identify these by giving them a name). Hope this help :)

Comment: JlayeredPane seems to fit the bill

Comment: @ControlAltDel – I tried this, but struggled to find a efficient way to resize the window with the components staying in the same place (e.g. zoom buttons stay in the right corner). Is there any way to allow for "dynamic resizing" with Absolute Positioning?

Comment: @Aphex I've used a ComponentListener to do what you're trying to do

Answer (score 1):

Use a `JLayeredPane`. This allows to have multiple "layers". Your map can be the bottom layer, while your buttons are placed in a layer on top of the map.

See [the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) for more information.